# zend using Decoration move serverside validation message next to textbox

Tags: php, zend-framework

In zend,

Using decorator how bring the validation message next to the text box.
 My current decoration code

```
$elementDecoration = array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'  => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td','width'=>'75%', 'class' => 'txt-td-field')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','width'=>'50%', 'class' => 'txt-td-label', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
            array(array('row'   => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr','valign'=>'top'),'width'=>'102%'),
        );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$fname = $this->createElement('text', 'first_name');
$fname ->setRequired(true)
       ->setAttrib('class','my_class')
       ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('Name is required'));
$fname->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

This will do the job.

Comment: i have tried, but not happened, i just copied u r code and tested, its not doing.

Answer (score 0):

try it with custom decorator:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_TdError extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $errors = parent::render('');
        return $content . "<td>" . $errors . "</td>";
    }
}
```

and then set decorators as following:

```
       $elementDecoration = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        array(array('data'  => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td','width'=>'75%', 'class' => 'txt-td-field')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','width'=>'50%', 'class' => 'txt-td-label', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
        'TdError',enter code here
        array(array('row'   => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr','valign'=>'top'),'width'=>'102%'),
    );
```

to set path to custom decorators call in form constructor

```
$this->addPrefixPath('My_Form_Decorator', 'My/Form/Decorator', 'decorator');
```

Comment: iam not much familiar in zend, can u tell me where i write the above class, controller, form, modle. i beleave in form, but plz confirm

Comment: ok, so you should have some folder for your own classes, for example /lib. add it to include paths and there create folders structure as written above: lib/My/Form/Decorator, there create file with name TdError.php. Place there class My_Form_Decorator_TdError.